# Prevent AddThis increasing social media count without sharing

Tags: configuration, addthis

I'm using [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) on my application, which displays a count of how many times the particular web page has been shared through one of the social networks available.

However, it seems this count increases even without actually sharing. For example, I can click on the Twitter icon, and the count will increase before I've actually submitted a tweet.

I thought this might just be a UI feature, but it seems the count is actually recorded as a refresh doesn't reset the count.

Here is a jsFiddle demo which shows how the count increases per click of an icon:

**[-- See Demo --](http://jsfiddle.net/wvMLr/)**

Are there any AddThis configuration settings for preventing this count from increasing, except when the page is actually shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to research I have done previously the developers of AddThis are trying to implement a better approach, but as of last month still nothing. Here is the response from their support website [Addthis support site](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/447384-counter-updates-on-click-not-share-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the unsaturated way to get a good performance . Addthis waits for close event and not ajax response. Is show the real number of shares to the rest of users.
You can use another plugin as mocanvas  to get the instant real shares, not in generator but when it is installed
http://share.mocanvas.com